# Pass data using Intent & bundle need to convert to int

Tags: android, android-intent, casting, integer, bundle

I'm trying to pass data to another activity, but after passing it I want to convert it to int is there a way to do that.

This my code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if(bundle != null) {

        checker.setText(bundle.getString("temperature"));
        String checkerHolder = checker.getText().toString();

        int finder = Intent.parseIntent(checkerHolder);

    }
```

The "checkerHolder" is the problem here look at the pic:

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: Try `int finder = Integer.valueOf(checkerHolder);`.

Comment: Use this one int intValue = Integer.parseInt(checkerHolder);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this line

```
int finder = Intent.parseIntent(checkerHolder);
```

with below one

```
    int finder = Integer.parseInt(checkerHolder);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just `int finder = Integer.parseInt(checkerHolder)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to get a `integer` at the other end, why don't you send it as an `integer` itself. You can do it easily as given below.

Add this in the sender activity

```
Bundle yourBundleName = new Bundle();

yourBundleName.putInt("yourKey", 100);
Intent yourIntentName = new Intent();
myIntent.putExtras(yourBundleName);

startActivity(yourIntentName);
```

On the receiving end simply get it as a Integer

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

if(extras !=null)
{
    int yourIntegerName = extras.getInt("yourKey");
}
```

This will reduce your conversion part.

If you still need it as a String and want to convert it to integer, you can use this

```
int yourIntegerName = Integer.parseInt(yourStringName)
```

Any troubles ? Feel free to ask.